# Compare and Swap Incorrect value

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, atomic

I have the following code for locking an object with a particular user ID

```
 public boolean acquireLock(Long id) {
   if (lock.compareAndSet(0L, id)) { 
    return true ; 
  }
  return false ; 
}
```

I acquire it in the following way:

```
      while(!parent.acquireLock(id)){
        System.out.println(lock.get());
        if (count++>1000000) {
          System.out.println(id + " Trying to acquire " + lock.get());
          DebugHandler.createException("Error, deadlock");

        }
      }
```

Release it as :

```
public boolean releaseLock(Long id) { 

  if (lock.compareAndSet(id, 0)) {
    System.out.println("Releasing Lock for " + id);
    return true ; 
  }
  else { 
    DebugHandler.createException("Lock not owned by current view. Thief");
    return false ;
  }

}
```

And declare the lock object as:

```
 private volatile AtomicLong lo = new AtomicLong(0);
```

except that I get the following odd behaviour and deadlock, which concludes with:

Id 45 trying to acquire  0

Ak, the value of the lock is systematically 0 but the  compare and swap test fails, believing it isn't 0.  (the counter to test for deadlock is reinitialised after I exit the loop)

Any ideas?

Comment: In your code you are using `this.getWorldID()` when acquiring the lock but your logging uses `this.id`. Please fix this and retest and let us know what the results are.

Comment: Is it really always 0? You can expect it to be 0 sometimes. It does not mean a dead lock, just that the spinlock is held by another thread. `AtomicLong` is atomic, but it is  *not* blocking.

Comment: Are you remembering to set `count` to 0 on success?

Comment: Yes it is always 0, at least for 1000000 iterations. And I do indeed reset count.

Comment: You're calling `parent.acquireLock()`, but printing `lock.get()`. Are those the *same* lock? `parent.lock` would seem more like the lock you're looking for.

Comment: Line above sets lock as  lock = parent.getLock(). Agreed confusing. poor coding on my part as not shown.

Comment: Making the AtomicLong volatile doesn't do much as you don't change the reference I assume. Make it final instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem with your code.  If you ever get some thread with an `id` that is zero, your locking scheme will break down, and two threads can end up holding the lock at the same time.

Fix:  Add a defensive check to your `acquireLock` and `releaseLock` methods to test that the `id` is non-zero.

As to how your code might get into an apparently deadlocked state:

- It could really be a real deadlock.  For instance, this could happen if a thread tries to acquire the lock for a given `id` when it already holds the lock for that `id`.  (Your lock as implemented is non-reentrant.)
- Your code could have failed to release the lock for a given `id`; e.g. because an exception was thrown and the normal call to `releaseLock` was skipped.

Comment: Ids are non 0 as they start getting allocated at 1.  Debugging output shows that a non 0 id thread is tryign to acquire lock with value 0, yet the CaS test still fails.

Comment: 1) You should include that defensive check for `0` anyway.  2) The reason that the CaS test is failing is that the lock is already held by something else.  I've given you two possible explanations for that.  There may be others too.